# Function to set namedtuple attributes?

Tags: python

I have a namedtuple that's a private property of a class instance. I want to create a new tuple based off an instance's namedtuple, but tuples are immutable, so I create a new one and just insert what I want. Is there a better way of doing this? It's extremely redundant, and I would like a specific function or so that would just take a namedtuple as a parameter and as the other parameter the attribute you want to change and it returns the new namedtuple. What would this look like?

Answer (score 1):

There's a [`_replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace) method for that:

```
new_namedtuple = old_namedtuple._replace(field_name=new_value)
```

Plus, it'll avoid the bug in your current code, where if two fields share the same value, your code might end up replacing the wrong one.